# What does "The Load" mean?

Tags: terminology

[This question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/59553/my-5e-character-isnt-very-fun-how-do-i-kill-them-off) calls their character "The Load". It's not a term I've heard, and the words are too common for Google to be helpful (that question is the only relevant one on the first few pages).

What does it mean?

Comment: http://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/59560/277 ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about a general English term rather than an RPG one.

Comment: I moved the TV Tropes link up to the question, should clarify for future users, but this isn't RPG specific and is OT.

Comment: Sorry, I assumed it was an RPG term.

Answer (score 8):

[The Load (Warning: TV Tropes)](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/TheLoad)

Basically they are someone that is just a 'load' that gets dragged around by the hero, but either doesn't really do anything productive most of the time and the hero has to spend time that they could use saving the world protecting this load from harm.

Comment: Goshdarn it, I should have thought of TV Tropes.