# My GM declines valid dialogue by my character due to his low Charisma; how can I change my GM's mind?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, ability-scores, problem-gm, social-stats

This is the first time I'm playing D&D. As a result, I may have botched the stats of my character. I have a low Charisma stat. However, in my understanding, this should only be a modifier to how well I play my character.

However, what I recently heard my DM tell me was, "Yeah, that line was great and it would work but you have too low Charisma to use it." Several times.

I want to convince my GM that just because I have a low CH stat, that doesn't mean I can only say, "Me Grug, me smash."

How can I do that?

EDIT: Since there are questions about what happned, the tl;dr is: there was an unfortunate accident involving a ruler's death ("ruler" of a kobold "empire"), that we were accused of. However, the ruler died with the "help" of magic, and we were just simple adventurers (a warrior, a barbarian and a rogue). After asking around for a bit, it became clear that juuuust by pure coincidence, it seems that after the ruler's death the court shaman will take over, and that he has been the ruler prior to the coronation of the now deceased one. I don't remember what I said exactly, but I wanted to point out to the main general (who seemed reasonable, honorable individual) that maybe, just maybe this is too much of a coincidence and they, with our help if they so wish, may investigate the issue more.

I was told "yeah, that's great reasoning, but you have 11 charisma, so you can't say that.".

Comment: Welcome! While your particular problem might be general enough, we ask that you tag your question with the exact game and edition you are playing. Being precise will raise the usefulness of answers.

Comment: It's pathfinder 1st edition, dnd 3.5? I'm not that knowledgable about dnd.

Comment: @Yuropoor: Pathfinder is technically different from D&D 3.5, though it is based on the 3.5 SRD and thus shares most of the same ruleset.

Comment: Without knowing what you said this is difficult to examine, some things about what you would know about a situation and thus  what you can say can to influence it can be determined by charisma

Comment: To note: An Ability Score of 10 or 11 is not low; it is, quite literally, exactly average.

Comment: Related: [How do character stats affect the personality of the character?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/89827/1204), [How much of a hindrance should my cleric's low intelligence score be?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/83457/1204)

Comment: I wonder how high the GM demands a CHA score to be before they allow PC's to say sensible things to NPC's?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A GM view of this question is discussed here: [How can I encourage players to role-play using their ability scores?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/136986/how-can-i-encourage-players-to-role-play-using-their-ability-scores?rq=1).

As implied in both the question and the accepted answer, skill checks are an appropriate tool in Pathfinder in this situation.  Very relevant to your situation, that answer suggests: "Use checks when players roleplay differently from their ability scores".

It sounds like you are talking about situations where Diplomacy would be an appropriate skill to useful; and you are allowed to use Diplomacy even if you have no ranks in the skill. See http://www.d20pfsrd.com/skills/ for more on skills.

So, I think you should ask your GM whether you can roll Diplomacy in these situations rather than the GM simply deciding that you are unsuccessful.