# How to swap a class level for another class

Tags: dnd-5e, multi-classing

So in a campaign I am currently a lv 4 Sorcerer/lv 1 Bard. Between sessions I tend to think about my character filling in gaps and in his backstory so to figure out how to play the character. He was orphaned and adopted by a significant figure in a church, he grew up in the church and was trained as a fighter from a very young age(flavor reason for why my sorcerer is proficient in the longsword), his background is acolyte for he is a fully ordained priest in his church although not a cleric. His natural abilities were in sorcerery, and while his adopted parents didn't like it they were supportive.

I gave him a level in bard for 2 reasons, our cleric likes to play tank and not healer and my wisdom sucks so cleric was out.

I feel I have 7 valid points here in summary why he should have been a sorcerer/paladin;

1. He was raised by the church
2. He was trained as a warrior
3. He is a full fledged priest of his church
4. He holds his church in great respect
5. He matches his god's alignment
6. He even prays to his god during breaks
7. I only choose bard for healing as a meta gaming decision

However I do not want to just ask my GM to retcon this decision, it'd set a bad example if nothing else. But he has said that he is open to homebrew(within reason) and requests for items we want to be added to the pool of randomly generated treasure he has.

Is there a way I can swap that bard level for paladin in the RAW or any known non-gamebreaking homebrew?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no RAW way to swap classes for already-taken levels.

However, if you want some precedent for retconning your character...

Adventurers League, the "organised play" system for D&D, allows you to change *almost anything* about your character before level 5. (Since you're now past that, AL wouldn't allow it... but it sounds like you're playing a non-AL home game, so you can ask the DM for some leeway)

Answer (score 3):

While it is entirely up to the DM, and you will have to ask, the things you want to keep in mind are whether you were Lawful Good, and whether your Bard Class was veering toward the College of Valor. Additionally, are the spells you took as a Bard the same spells that a Paladin can eventually cast? Such as *Cure Wounds* or *Heroism*?

Does your Bard use a weapon that the Paladin might favor, like some kind of similar sword? Do you have a heraldry title, a mount, or similar equipment and paraphernalia indicating that the game world would think you were a Paladin, or could pass for one?

If these things are true, then the DM and other players may be more willing to accept the retcon, but in no way is it standard official rules, although there are precedents for reflavoring or rewriting characters.

**Legally, you can do this** with a *Wish*, by acquiring a *Luckblade*, *Ring of Wishes*, or bribing an Archmage.

However, the access to magical items in 5e is toned down significantly, as is the wealth, so you may be better off asking for special (outside the rules) permission to rewrite your character, rather than waiting another 3-10 levels for the opportunity to *Wish* yourself out of this situation.

in addition to wish, you can also use a True Polymorph to fix your character. Here's the relevant text:

> **Creature into Creature.** If you turn a creature into another kind o f
>   creature, the new form can be any kind you choose whose challenge
>   rating is equal to or less than the target’s (or its level, if the
>   target doesn’t have a challenge rating). The target’s game statistics,
>   including mental ability scores, are replaced by the statistics of the
>   new form. It retains its alignment and personality. The target assumes
>   the hit points o f its new form, and when it reverts to its normal
>   form, the creature returns to the number o f hit points it had before
>   it transformed. If it reverts as a result o f dropping to 0 hit
>   points, any excess damage carries over to its normal form. As long as
>   the excess damage doesn’t reduce the creature’s normal form to 0 hit
>   points, it isn’t knocked unconscious. The creature is limited in the
>   actions it can perform by the nature o f its new form, and it can’t
>   speak, cast spells, or take any other action that requires hands or
>   speech unless its new form is capable o f such actions. The target’s
>   gear melds into the new form. The creature can’t activate, use, wield,
>   or otherwise benefit from any o f its equipment.
>
> **If you concentrate on this spell for the full duration, the**
>   **transformation becomes permanent.**

You will find a wizard more willing to cast True Polymorph than Wish, because wish has a chance of being taken away each time it is cast. Warlocks and Bards can also cast it. Sorcerers and Wizards cast Wish, so which ever one you know that reaches 17th level first, that's your Fairy Godmother to do this legally by RAW.

Comment: He is almost 100% sorcerer with the only bard aspects to him at this time being him having healing word and cure wounds. I've already pointed out the backstory reasons why he is more cleric and by extension paladin than he is a bard. He is not an entertainer.

Comment: Backstory is a good argument for DM choices, but sadly not relevant to the Rules. If you want to do it legally, Polymorph Any Object is your best bet. Also, be sure to take off all your equipment first before having the spell cast, or you will lose it all.

Comment: Additionally, my character follows the god Selune(Sword coast) who is Chaotic Good

Comment: make that True Polymorph, not PAO. 5e doesn't have hireling tables for wizards. Your DM may require you appeal at your Temple, or simply rewrite your backstory with you as a paladin. But the only hard rules to make the change are 9th level spells.

Comment: I feel i need to clarify something; I'm not looking to ditch my sorcerer levels. I want to move the single bard level to paladin.

Comment: then ask your DM to let you find a "wish" ring with one wish left in it.  That way you can do it legally in game with the wish ring (and a "gentleman's agreement" to use the wish for this!)

Answer (score 2):

### Ask your GM to retcon your decisions

Yes, it sets a bad example, and I'd personally frown upon a player who approaches me with a topic like this. But your GM has no choice, if he wants the table to remain fun for everyone. His choices are:

1. Deny the request. You stick to the "messy" character you made, and your fun suffers, which isn't good.
2. Deny the request. You passive-aggressively send your character off to [retirement](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/59640/23064) or death, then make a new one with the same story, which might ruin some players' sense of immersion, which isn't good. (I know, one of my players tried this: *"I am KETH! Keth's younger brother. We're all named Keth!"*)
3. Allow the request. Accept that new players will make mistakes, and be a little more sterner with this player when it comes to background choices/improvisation.

---

As a sidenote: It looks like you want to play a [Favored Soul Sorcerer](https://media.wizards.com/2017/dnd/downloads/UA-RevisedSubclasses.pdf) from the UA. They are sorcerers with Cleric abilities, including healing. The DM may be a little more lenient if you're simply changing archetypes!

Comment: I refuse to simply 'remake' my character. If my character dies or is unable to be played anymore I intend to use a completely new character. I very much love role playing and writing as an author. However that change in bloodline you suggested would change a lot more of my character than just moving a subclass level elsewhere. Not to mention also move that subclass level into the main class.

Comment: @Clarus_Nox I understand. Then, it would seem you are the one who have no choice but to stick to the 1st option, as by RAW, there is no way (maybe wish -but let's be real) to achieve what you want. I just hope it's still fun for you despite it. :)

Comment: I'm sure I'll manage, but I'll go ahead and ask him in private and see what he thinks. The bard level was his suggestion too when I told him I was considering going for the multi-class to contribute to the healing role.

Comment: @Clarus_Nox Cut yourself some slack :) Did you even know the Favored Soul Sorcerer was an option? If you had, wouldn't you have picked that up at 1st-level? It seems like a _perfect_ fit for the character you're describing.

Comment: No, my character's faith was to be almost entirely flavor and roleplay originally. I only started looking into doing healing because as I said our cleric and druid spend the battles tanking and only healing afterwords. And our ranger likes to play his character as a lunatic so not much healing from him either... He literally said nothing after noticing 9 hobgoblins had surrounded us. The decision to multiclass for healing abilities was entirely meta game planning.

Comment: I don't think it's meta-gaming.  "Hmm, we seem to be getting hurt quite a bit; maybe I'd better go on that St John Ambulance course" seems an entirely reasonable in-game reaction.